# Where to find custom metrics in Azure Portal

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-application-insights, metrics, telemetry

I'm trying to send custom metrics to an App Service in Azure Portal given an instrumentation key. I have the following code running in .NET Core as part of a Background service:

```cs
public override async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    try
    {
        TelemetryClient telemetry = new TelemetryClient();
        telemetry.TrackEvent("new event");
        var sample = new MetricTelemetry();
        sample.Name = "metric name";
        sample.Value = 42.3;
        telemetry.TrackMetric(sample);
        telemetry.Flush();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _logger.LogError($"{e.Message} {e.StackTrace}");
    }
}
```

This sample code comes from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics).

However I'm not sure if these metrics are even reaching the Azure instance or where to look for them. I went to Application Insights > MyInstance > Logs and found a table there named 'customEvents'. However I can't query over it. On the Metrics tabs I only get the default metrics namespace which shows the default metrics available in Azure, but not any new custom metrics.

Comment: Did you have App insight working before ?

Comment: Yes I can see the logs coming in there, as in logs generated through plain ILogger

Comment: I see that your method has override can you please add to your question more information about it? Also is it azure function or web api or smth else?

Comment: It's running inside a Background service

Comment: Inside background service? can you be more specific?

Comment: Yes like this one: public class ProcessCustomMetrics : BackgroundService However I don't think this is relevant for the question since the code is executing just fine

Comment: Do you have in your startup   services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService(); ?

Comment: @Rafael please try adding `telemetry.Flush()` after `telemetry.TrackMetric(sample);`(sample is [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/application-insights-use-case-for-telemetryclient-flush-calls/)). And if you run the project in visual studio, you can also check in the `visual studio output window` to see if the metric is sent or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that you create a new `telemetry client` by using this line of code: `TelemetryClient telemetry = new TelemetryClient();`, but the new `telemetry client` does not configure a `InstrumentationKey`. Then the `custom events` / `custom metrics` are not sent by using `telemetry.TrackEvent` / `telemetry.TrackMetric` methods.

You should change it like below in `Worker.cs`:

```cs
namespace WorkerService3
{
    public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

        //define a telemetry client here, and use it in your following code
        private TelemetryClient telemetry;

        public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, TelemetryClient tc)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            telemetry = tc;
        }

        public override async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            try
            {
                //do not create a another telemetry client, use the one defined in class-level.
                //TelemetryClient telemetry = new TelemetryClient();
                telemetry.TrackTrace("StartAsync: new message");
                telemetry.TrackEvent("StartAsync: new event");
                var sample = new MetricTelemetry();
                sample.Name = "StartAsync metric name";
                sample.Value = 11.55;
                telemetry.TrackMetric(sample);
                telemetry.Flush();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"{e.Message} {e.StackTrace}");
            }

        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
           //other code
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my `Program.cs`:

```cs
namespace WorkerService3
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
                });
    }
}
```

This is my appsettings.json:

```json
{
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": "your application insights InstrumentationKey"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

After the code is executed, wait for a few minutes, I can search custom metrics / custom events in azure portal -> my application insights -> Logs(for custom events, query the `customEvents` table):

[image]

Comment: Correct, not injecting the telemetry client through DI was the issue, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

In my startup I do have

```cs
 services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
```

As you said you are using background worker

1. Install package nuget  `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService`
2. in your startup:

- ```cs
  public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
          Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
              .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
              {
                 .....
                  services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
              });
  ```

Simple way to find would be to go to app insight transaction search and search for event name

[image]

Then you click on event and you will go to next view

[image]

Thats how I would check if you events are actually logged.

Also I just run queries

```
customMetrics
| where name == "metric name"

customEvents
| where name == "Error.PageNotFound"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right place, however I'm not getting any custom logs. Is there anything wrong with my code? I have the same line as suggested here on Startup

Comment: @Rafael silly question are you sure that code is getting hit?

Comment: Yes I can hit it using a breakpoint so it's definitely running